# Django postgres remove all data created after a point in time

Tags: python, django, postgresql

How can I remove all the objects which were created after some timestamp `t` in django?

Plainly, I need to remove all the objects (all rows in all tables) which have `created_at > t`. Is there any better solution than writing this:

```
models = [Model1, Model2, ..., ModelN]
for model in models:
   model.objects.filter(created_at__gt=t).delete()
```

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? Only thing you could add is getting the list of Models dynamically.

Comment: @WilliamR.Marchand I am relatively new to django so I am not sure there are no better ways, also I don't know how to get the list dynamically :)

Comment: user6731765 shows you how. from django.db import models
models_list = models.get_models()

Answer (score 1):

One possibly improvement is to use `get_models`

```
from django.db import models
models_list = models.get_models()
```

to automatically get the list of models, then delete them the way you do.

To only get the models for a specific application, you can do

```
from django.apps import apps
app = apps.get_config("app name")
models_list = app.models
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Django app registry `django.apps.apps`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/applications/) allows you to get all models.

```python
import datetime

import django.apps

red_letter_day = datetime.datetime(1949, 6, 8)

for model in django.apps.apps.get_models():
    model.objects.filter(created_at__gt=red_letter_day).delete()
```